# Shared library in Websphere 7

Tags: java, jar, websphere, ear

I am deploying my EAR on WAS 6 having 3 modules, in all of those 3 modules there are many jar files it makes my EAR heavy, to avoid that i want to use Shared Library wizard of Websphere. Please provide me link or tell me what changes i have to make in my code or resource or any .xml files.
I am using below link to configure my JARs in Websphere [Websphere Shared Library link 1](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tcws_sharedlib.html?lang=en)
[Link 2](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7JFU_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/crun_classload.html?cp=SS7JFU_7.0.0/1-8-6-0&lang=en) [Link 3](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/06062009015816PMWEBP3Y.htm)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15):

This is how shared libray is referenced.

Logon to the Websphere Application Server console.

- Go to Environment -> Shared Libraries

  1. Create your own Shared Library. Add the classpath pointing to your JAR files.
  2. Apply and save this configuration.
  3. Now, Go to Servers -> Application Servers -> Select the server-> Java and Process Management -> ClassLoader.
  4. Click on that class loader.
  5. Click on the Shared Library References
  6. Click on Add.
  7. Add your shared library.
  8. Save and restart Websphere Servers.

Comment: While making EAR what changes i have to make in EAR ?  I am making EAR using Eclipse/RAD, not using any tools like ANT or MAVEN

Comment: Shared library is used when you have common lib files which will be used for many modules. And to build common lib, create another java project and your jar/lib files will be there and in your ear, import the reference of class files which are in common lib jar files.

Comment: Thanks for your help but in case of websphere server we dont have to create a new project and deploy it in WAS. We just have to add Shared library paths in WAS and then point our application to it.

Comment: Yes, You are right. You dont need to deploy them in WAS. Just need to give reference SharedLib path.

Comment: thank you is working, I'm handling NoClassDefFoundError at runtime but adding the jar in the shared library seems working

Answer (score 2):

Thanks all for HELP.. Finally i found solution.

1. First remove all .jar files from your EAR even from different
   modules.
2. Save all .jar files in some location.
3. Go to WAS admin console > Environment > Shared Library and
   give a suitable name and mention classpath of all the required jar
   files. eg C:/libs/ojdbc14.jar. Restart WAS.
4. Then deploy your EAR on WAS but don't start it.
5. Go to Admin console > Application lists > select your application > Shared Library Reference, there you will see all the modules of your EAR. Select Checkbox next to it and Click Reference Library.
6. Here you will see all the Shared library you saved earlier, add them to all modules.
7. Now start your application.

Comment: Above approach works when you are deploying your application after creating EAR and deploying it on server using console. But if you want to debug your application from eclipse/RAD and server is already configured in eclipse/RAD then you need to make following entry in deployment.xml file (PROJECT-EAR --> META-INF --> ibmconfig --> deployment.xml ) :
'<!--<classloader xmi:id="Classloader_818319250" mode="PARENT_LAST"/> -->
<classloader xmi:id="Classloader_818319250" mode="PARENT_FIRST">
 <libraries libraryName="YOUR_LIBS_NAME" sharedClassloader="true"/>
</classloader>'

Answer (score 1):

A common problem that I faced with Shared Libraries was multiple jar occurrences. So,
When installing web-apps under WAS, you can set the class loading policy in the options for that application (or globally on server/node level)

If the policy options are (search) "parent first" / "parent last" and one class loader per application or per war. The default is "parent first / war". If your web-app comes with all jars it needs you'll be better off with the policy set to "parent last / application". Also if you edit your web.xml to reflect changes, be sure to set "use binary configuration" otherwise it will always use what it stored during install.

You get the class loading option under
Wepsphere applications>>click on the application name there you could see the class loader option.